# why are my local links displaying about:blank#blocked

Tags: html

Hello I have been working on making a simple website.I had added a link to another page but everytime I use the link the page is blank and this error is emitted in the url about:blank#blocked.
I have used chrome and opera to test this.

**Index**

```
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="header">
        <div id="headerText">
            <h1>MyPortfolio</h1>
            <h2>D</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div>
            <a href="skills.html">Skills</a>
        <a>Qualifiactions</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">

    </div>
    <div class="aboutMe">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other Page(skills.html)

```
<body >
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="header">
        <div id="headerText">
            <h1>Skills</h1>
            <h2>D</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div>
            <a href="ordercoffee.html">OrderCoffe</a>
        <a>Qualifiactions</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">

    </div>
    <div class="aboutMe">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had my testing-new-things FTP open so I directly pasted your scripts to create two pages: index.html and skills.html and they worked as written on Chrome web browser.
[image: View after clicking link to skills.html]

About Blank is a web page built into your browser when the page has nothing to display. Perhaps check you are actually uploading your files to the correct directory- try testing them from your desktop as two .html files located in the same folder and dragging them to a new tab to display. If that doesn't work, try updating your html script with the correct syntax for creating a new document. Here is an example- remove the script tags which are used for javascript.
https://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/

And try basic "hello world" test documents to make sure everything is working before trying your script again.